How can I make the border-image round
I want to make that square border round around the main circle which contains icons.
I tried using ChatGPT and Google but didn't seem to find any results that work. I am a newbie on this thing.


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500');
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}

.status {
    position: absolute;
    left: 350px; bottom: 15px;
    bottom: 3%; left: 16.5%;
}

.health, .armor, .hunger, .thirst {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    color: #A12222;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #A12222;
    background: 
    linear-gradient(#1D1E20 0 0) padding-box,
    linear-gradient(0deg, #A12222 0%, #1D1E20 20%, #1D1E20 80%, #A12222) border-box;
}

.health-outline,
.armor-outline,
.hunger-outline,
.thirst-outline {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #FFB54B;
}

.health-outline::before,
.armor-outline::before,
.hunger-outline::before,
.thirst-outline::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient( hsl(0, 100%, 50%), hsl(0, 100%, 50%) 80%, transparent 80%, transparent 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Job Center</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="ui">
            <div class="status">
                <div class="health-outline">
                    <div class="health">
                        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="armor-outline">
                    <div class="armor">
                        <i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hunger-outline">
                    <div class="hunger">
                        <i class="fas fa-drumstick-bite"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thirst-outline">
                    <div class="thirst">
                        <i class="fas fa-wine-bottle"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



Hello, I want to make that square border round around the main circle which contains icons.
I tried using ChatGPT and Google but didn't seem to find any results that work. I am a newbie on this thing.

Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to ask a good question. Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add all the relevant code to include a [mre].

Let try it


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.status {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
}

.health,
.armor,
.hunger,
.thirst {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  color: #A12222;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #A12222;
  background: linear-gradient(#1D1E20 0 0) padding-box, linear-gradient(0deg, #A12222 0%, #1D1E20 20%, #1D1E20 80%, #A12222) border-box;
}

.health-outline,
.armor-outline,
.hunger-outline,
.thirst-outline {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #FFB54B;
}

.health-outline::before,
.armor-outline::before,
.hunger-outline::before,
.thirst-outline::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient( hsl(0, 100%, 50%) 0%, hsl(0, 100%, 50%) 80%, transparent 80%, transparent 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Job Center</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="ui">
    <div class="status">
      <div class="health-outline">
        <div class="health">
          <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="armor-outline">
        <div class="armor">
          <i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hunger-outline">
        <div class="hunger">
          <i class="fas fa-drumstick-bite"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="thirst-outline">
        <div class="thirst">
          <i class="fas fa-wine-bottle"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




This didn't work, I added the full snippet.

I just edited the code above. Please try it and let me know

Yeah, this works but can you also make a gap between the middle circle and the border. I editted the snippet in the first post. Design I'm trying to make

Here you are !!! Let edit the status class like this
.status {
position: absolute;
left: 350px; bottom: 15px;
bottom: 3%; left: 16.5%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
gap: 16px;
}

I didn't mean this :) Can you have a look here at what I'm trying to recreate ? https://imgur.com/6jRIZal

I just updated the code above. Please check. I added more css for status class

This didn't quite fix that... Have you taken a look at the image ? :)

I fixed. Please recheck the code

This didn't fix it but I have found a solution online, Thanks !
